# Workaround for the definite integral $\int_1^2 x \ln\left(\frac1{x^2+1}\right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_1^2  x \ln\left(\frac1{x^2+1}\right)\,dx$$
I asked about the indefinite form of this one a while ago and one of the comments got me thinking. Is there a way to calculate this definite integral "directly", without wrestling with the polygarithm?
I noticed it's an odd function, thus $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=0$, but I'm not sure how to follow up on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is all too easy.
$$\int x\ln\frac1{x^2+1}\,dx$$
$$=-\frac12\int2x\ln(x^2+1)\,dx$$
$$=-\frac12(x^2+1)(\ln(x^2+1)-1)+K$$
where we have used $\int\ln x\,dx=x(\ln x-1)+K$.

Comment: That's it? Wow I sure feel stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that by integration by parts
$$\int_1^2  x \ln\left(\frac1{x^2+1}\right)\,dx=-\int_1^2 x\ln(x^2+1)\,dx=
-\left[\frac{(x^2+1)}{2}\cdot\ln(x^2+1)\right]_1^2+\int_1^2 x\,dx.$$
P.S. On the other hand you will need the polygarithm for
$\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x}\ln(x^2+1)\,dx$.

Comment: But wait. Using this formula we get $$-[\frac{(x^2+1)ln(x^2+1)+x^2}2 ]_1^2$$
While using the method below the integral becomes $$-[\frac{(x^2+1)ln(x^2)}2]_1^2$$
Which is the correct one?

Comment: @Moss You can check the right formula by differentiation:
$D(-(1+x^2)/2\ln(x^2+1)+x^2/2)=-\ln(x^2+1)x$

Comment: I did.
$$-[\frac{(x^2+1)ln(x^2+1)+x^2}2 ]_1^2=-\frac{5ln(5)-2ln(2)+3}2$$
$$-[\frac{(x^2+1)ln(x^2)}2]_1^2=-5ln(2)$$

Comment: It should be
$[\frac{-(x^2+1)\ln(x^2+1)+x^2}2 ]_1^2=\frac{-5\ln(5)+2\ln(2)+3}2.$ Check the signs!

Comment: @Moss Did you find the right one?

Comment: Nope. No answer on the book. Maybe I'll work some more on it on my own. Thanks anyway.